# Relation between preprocessing and translation

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, translation

Do we have any relationship between preprocessing and translation process? and when does preprocesing occurs before or after translation process ?

Answer (score 2):

The term **pre**-processing would seem to imply that it occurs *before* any compilation is performed.

Comment: `seem` ? Could you please suggest me a good resource to read about it ?

Comment: You can read about the translation phases in the C99 standard at 5.1.1.2 , look e.g. in the free draft here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I was just being a bit of a smart ass.  It does occur before any code generation is done, otherwise how would you expect the compiler to deal with things like macros?